# Cannot delete the malware bytes icon in macOS menu bar

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar

I cannot delete a menu extra icon from my macOS menu bar.

If I click the command button and drag it off of the menu bar, it shows a circle with a line through it, which is an indicator to me that this action is not possible.

It is from the Malwarebytes program which I deleted, and the program is definitely no longer functioning.  Is there another method of removing this icon from my macOS menu bar??

Answer (score 8):

Only first-party menu bar apps can be ⌘-dragged off the menu bar.

To remove third-party menu bar apps, you should refer to the specific app settings.

For Malwarebytes, you can [turn off the menu bar app from Malwarebytes preferences → Hide application icon](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/206483-uninstall/?do=findComment&comment=1149862). To properly uninstall Malwarebytes if you no longer want the software, [open Malwarebytes, and go to "help" > "uninstall Malwarebytes"](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/206483-uninstall/?do=findComment&comment=1216867).

Answer (score 6):

If you moved to trash for deleting the app and the icon is still sticked in menu bar;

Go to > Activity Monitor -> Search for `FrontendAgent` and double click on it click Open Files and Ports tab.

You ll see the Malwarebytes source path like /Library/Application Support/Malwarebytes/
Open the terminal:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Application\ Support/Malwarebytes/` replace this path with have you seen in Activity monitor screen if not the same one and run the command.

Then `Quit` the job from activity monitor.

Thats all.